# youtube <video> element always comes up empty in firefox contentscript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

main.js

```
highLevelTab.attach({
  contentScriptFile: "./yt-controls.js"
});
```

/data/yt-controls.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  var video = window.document.getElementsByTagName("video");
  console.log(video);
});
```

`video` comes up as `{"0":{}}`. Do I need to inject this into the page script in order to get the actual values?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use `unsafeWindow` in firefox to access the page as it is, after all scripts on the page have messed with it, as detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts#Access_objects_defined_by_page_scripts). So,

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  var video = unsafeWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("video");
  console.log(video);
});
```